# Beautiful Soup: Extract text at the a anchor after url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some html where the URL in the a href comes before the title that would appear on the page. I am trying to get at that title and url and extract that into a data frame. The following code is what I have so far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://patentsview.org/download/data-download-tables'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all("div", class_="file-title")
print(results)

pd.DataFrame([a.text for a in soup.select('.file-title a')], columns=['Title'])
```

As it stands, I only have the one column I would like the results to be in the following format:

| Title | URL |
| --- | --- |
| application | URL1 |
| assignee | URL2 |
| ... | ... |

I was following this page on [Real Python](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/) but I have have come to a standstill since I cannot seem to translate their next part into my needs.

Any help with this would be wonderful. Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT 1: I have made some edits to the original question. I want to expand it to also include the URL that the title is attached to in a second column. I have also incorporated the code that was provided on the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `.text` on the `<a>` in each of the `<div>` to print your information:

```
for e in soup.find_all("div", class_="file-title"):
    print(e.a.text)
```

or with `css selector`:

```
for a in soup.select('.file-title a'):
    print(a.text)
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://patentsview.org/download/data-download-tables'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for e in soup.find_all("div", class_="file-title"):
    print(e.a.text)
```

###### Output

```
application
assignee
botanic
cpc_current
cpc_group
cpc_subgroup
cpc_subsection
figures
...
```

Or as `DataFrame`

```
pd.DataFrame([a.text for a in soup.select('.file-title a')], columns=['Title'])
```

###### Output:

| Title |
| --- |
| application |
| assignee |
| botanic |
| cpc_current |
| cpc_group |
| cpc_subgroup |
| cpc_subsection |
| figures |
| foreigncitation |
| foreign_priority |
| government_interest |
| government_organization |
| inventor |
| ipcr |
| lawyer |
| location |
| mainclass |
| mainclass_current |

---

## EDIT

Based on comment to get both "Title" and "Url"

```
data = []
for a in soup.select('.file-title a'):
    data.append({
        'Title':a.text,
        'Url':a['href']
    })
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Fantastic! I had been working on this for quite some time. Should just come here sooner. Thank you for your help.

Comment: As a follow up, what if I wanted the URL then to be in column 2. I tried pd.DataFrame([ahref.text for ahref in soup.select('.a href')], columns=['Title']) just to see if I can pull it and got an empty data frame. If you have time, could you also show how to make this second column?

Comment: There should only be one question at a time, but take a look at my EDIT of the answer.